# How do you include a git module in Android Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, okhttp

I have a custom version of a dependency (OkHttp) that I want to include in an Android Gradle project. It is hosted on GitHub at https://github.com/cloewen8/okhttp-ntrip/tree/agra-gps. Now I want to include it in an Android project.

There are several approaches I have found for this. Using jitpack, a sub-project using a git submodule or using a Gradle source dependency. Jitpack is unable to compile it () and using a submodule causes way more problems.

My current approach is with a source dependency. But when it builds, I get the error `No variants found for ':app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists.` It is a standard Android project structure, I have installed the correct SDK and the app will build without this dependency in build.gradle. What am I missing?

In settings.gradle:

```kotlin
import org.gradle.api.initialization.resolve.RepositoriesMode

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
// The source of the dependency is added here
sourceControl {
    gitRepository("https://github.com/cloewen8/okhttp-ntrip.git") {
        producesModule("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
    }
}

rootProject.name = "AgraGPS"
include ':app'
```

And in the app's build.gradle (removed unrelated sections):

```kotlin
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.agragps.agragps"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 3_000_000
        versionName "3.00.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }
    namespace 'com.agragps.agragps'
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.10.0"))
    // This is the dependency that causes the build error
    implementation('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp') {
        version {
            branch = 'agra-gps'
        }
    }
}
```